# How to connect AWS CLI with Key ID & Secret Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm unable to connect AWS instance with Secret key and Key ID.Usually We are using multi factor authentication to connect to AWS(ask for rsa token) and then we connect to instance using the session manager.We are really uncomfortable in using the AWS  in session manager. 
Steps tried :

```
$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
Default region name [None]: us-west-2
Default output format [None]: json
```

This has been successful , But it says You are not authorized to connect to an instance. Where I can enter my username/password . I didnt specify which account I'm trying to connect.However I'm able to access from the session manager

```
aws ssm start-session --target "i-1234567890abcdef0"
```

Please guide me clearly . Im noob to AWS . Just trying to ease our daily activities.

Comment: I do not have PEM file and cannot get it for security reasons.

Comment: If the access key and secret key you have mentioned in the question are real, please delete them and regenerate them as they have been leaked and your account is already compromised. Scrub them before you post them again.

Comment: Is Looks like real, AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE???

Comment: Do your credentials actually have SSM permissions, for example AmazonSSMFullAccess? Please review https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-access.html for setting up your IAM permissions to use SSM and for setting up the instance to actually allow SSM access. PS you don't need to specify which account you're trying to use - it's inferred by AWS from the access key you use.

Comment: Yes it is SSM full access. But still cannot connect . Is it possible for them to block via AWS cli . BUt I have full access to Session manager .

Comment: Does your instance belong to `us-west-2` region?

Comment: IT is changed on purpose .

Comment: @Asdfg , I have tried almost many things since today morning . I cannot get through without pem key . Do you think MFA is the blocker.

Comment: Is it a coincidence that you have specified the same AWS Access Key Id and AWS Secret Access Key as in the [CLI configuration guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html)? If you read that page you will learn how you can obtain your personal credentials instead.

Comment: @matsev,Not coincidence , I have copied from there only . I have read that document , I have implemented it . Didnt work out . Can anyone provide me just 4 5 steps to get it resolved

Comment: @Varshini you need to follow steps 1-6 in the **To get the access key ID and secret access key for an IAM user** paragraph of the [CLI configuration guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html) to create your _personal_ credentials and use them instead of the example credentials provided in the documentation. Important, as stated in the documentation, _Keep the keys confidential in order to protect your AWS account, and never email them. Do not share them outside your organization_, i.e. do not share any personal credentials on a public forum like SO.

Comment: @matsev I have been trying this for last six hours I'm unable to do it . That is the reason raised a request .Thanks very much for links , I have read those links many times . it didnt help me .

Comment: You can't. aws-cli can only connect through SSM. Since you mentioned PEM, I assume you want to connect over SSH. Which it sounds like you are not allowed to do by design. Talk to your managers or security people. This isn't something that SO can help you with.

Comment: I do not use pem file to connect with SSM , we are trying to connect using RSA token to authenticate and will get associated with my id already and I will be authenticated then redirected to my session manager . I never used PEM file.We have sec key/Key id. what should I do now

Comment: @Varshini Could you please clarify what you mean by "We are using multi factor authentication to connect to AWS" and "we are trying to connect using RSA token to authenticate"? When precisely are you using MFA (eg console login, or when running the SSM command)? Do the permissions on your IAM User require MFA to start the SSM session? In fact, can you edit your question to show us the policy that is currently granting you permission to use SSM?

Comment: We have a AD login, Once we logged in, It will ask for RSA token to access aws . Once access is granted , We are able to do anything in AWS . Starting the session doesn't really need permission .

Comment: No solution yet..

Comment: this might help https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-session-token.html